# Error for initialize_python in R studio when import python functions

Tags: python, r, shinyapps

I am trying to use the specific python version in scripts.R file and my code is like this

```
use_python("/home/username/foldername2/Python-3.7.2", required=T)
```

And then I try to import python scripts I created as a function to use in scripts.R

```
 source_python("function.py")
```

However, the error is that :
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.

Does anyone know what happens?

Thank you

Best

Comment: And should the python 3.7.2 be installed in usr/bin or any other folders are fine?

Comment: Is there really a `python` .exe in that directory? Can you start a shell session at command line: `$ /home/username/foldername2/Python-3.7.2/python`? Assuming Linux, usually software is not installed in user folders.